# Objective C Object Functioning & Passing Arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, arrays

I apologise if this has been asked before but I can't find the info I need.

Basically I want a UITableView to be populated using info from a server, similar to the SeismicXML example. I have the parser as a separate object, is it correct to alloc, init an instance of that parser & then tell RootViewController to make it's table data source a copy of the parser's array.

I can't include code because I haven't written anything yet, I'm just trying to get the design right before I start. Perhaps something like:

```
xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc] init];

[xmlParser getXMLData];

// Assuming xmlParser stores results in an array called returnedArray

self.tableDataSource = xmlParser.returnedArray
```

Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't want to do this. You don't want your view controller directly accessing the array of the data-model. This would work in the technical sense but it would be fragile and likely to fail as the project scaled.

As the projects grow in complexity, you will want to increasingly wrap your data model object (in this case the xmlParser) in protective layers of methods to control and verify how the data model changes. Eventually, you will have projects with multiple views, multiple view controllers as well as information entering from both the user and URLs. You need to get into the habit of using the data-model object not just a dumb store you dump stuff into but as an active manager and verifier of your data.

In a situation like this I would have my data-model's array completely wrapped by making it a @protected or @private property. Then I would have dedicated methods for fetching or inserting data into the actual array inside the data-model class itself. No objects outside of the data-model should actually have direct access to the array or have knowledge of its indexes.

So, in this case your data-model would have something like:

```
- (NSString *) textForLineAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) anIndexPath{
    //... do bounds checking for the index
    NSString *returnString=[self.privateArray objectAtIndex:anIndexPath.row];
    if (returnString=='sometest'){
        return returnString;
    }
    return @""; //return an empty string so the reciever won't nil out and crash
}
```

as well as a `setTextForLineAtPath:` method for setting the line if you need that.

The general instructional materials do not spend enough (usually none) time talking about the data-model but the data-model is actually the core of the program. It is where the actual logic of the application resides and therefore it should be one of the most complex and thoroughly tested class in your project.

A good data-model should be interface agnostic i.e. it should work with a view based interface, a web based interface or even the command line. It should neither know nor care that its data will be displayed in a tableview or any other interface element or type.

When I start a new project, the first thing I do is comment out the '[window makeKeyAndVisible];' in the app delegate. Then I create my data-model class and test it old-school by loading data and logging the outputs. Only when it works exactly how I wish it to do I then proceed to the user interface.

So, think real hard about what you want the app to do on an abstract level. Encode that logic in a custom class. Isolate the data from all direct manipulation from any other object. Verify all inputs to the data before committing.

It sounds like a lot of work and it is. It feels like overkill for a small project and in many cases it is. However, getting the habit early will pay big dividends very quickly as your apps grow in complexity.

Comment: +1 I totally agree that the docs are poor in explaining the absolute necessity of a well-considered model layer. Most of the examples just throw data into an NSString or NSArray, and students are misled into copying this. The student isn't taught that these examples are over-simplifying the model layer because they're focused on other pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Mac programmer and not an iPhone programmer; but on the mac, 
`self.tableDataSource = xmlParser.returnedArray` is not correct. You are supposed to either bind the table's content to an Array Controller (if iPhone has one?) or set the datasource outlet to your RootViewController.

In your rootview controller, you would implement the methods:

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

For `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you would return a `UITableViewCell` with the data you received from the XML parsing according to the index path like so:

```
UITableCell *myCell = [UITableCell new]; 
myCell.textLabel.text = [parsedXMLArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:indexPath.length-1]];
return myCell;
```

(*Something people don't know is that you can use the + new class method on all NSObject subclasses which automatically call alloc/init.*)

For `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` just return the count of the data array:

```
return parsedXMLArray.count;
```

Comment: The iPhone does not support binding nor does it have collection controllers. Your advice is sound for Cocoa but doesn't closely apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. You want the data source to be an object that implements the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol; what I would do in this situation is create an object that implements that protocol *and* parses XML, so that you can `alloc`-`init` it, then set the data source to that object and have it update the table view as appropriate. So based off your code (and assuming you're running within the table view's controller):

```
XMLParserAndDataSource xpads = [[XMLParserAndDataSource alloc] init];
[xpads getXMLData];
self.tableView.dataSource = xpads;
```

It's probably a good idea to give this class itself a reference to an [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object, so you can use that to parse the XML, then provide convenience methods (like `getXMLData`) as well as the UITableViewDataSource methods for your own use. (If you go this route, you should also make your XMLParserAndDataSource class implement the more useful of the NSXMLParser delegate methods, and use them as appropriate to update your table view.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't edit my question nor post replies, can only post my response as answer.

@TechZen: I'm somebody who tries to form analogies, helps me understand. What you're saying is something like: My original idea was like going into the file room & dumping all the originals on my desk to work on where as you suggest the object be more like an organised file clerk who will search through the data for me and only return the specific datum that I need while being the only one with direct access to that data.
Have I understood correctly?

@Tim: What if I later need the parser to get data for something which is not a table? That's why I thought to dump it into an array & let the caller decide what to do with the data. Would you suggest a second object that would supply the data in the newly required form? (Am I sort of one the right track here or way off?)

Comment: Yes, a very good analogy. It's so good I intend to steal it. ;-) That is exactly what it is like. You go up to the counter, request a file from the clerk, he disappears back into he dark recesses of the stacks and then returns with the file. You never see how the files are organized of what he does to retrieve the file.